# How can i initialize array of object with rand() function of a three parameterized constructor?

Tags: c++, arrays

This is a program for find the largest and smallest Box from an array.  How can I generate a random number automatically and store it in the array?

How can I auto generate the length, width and height and store it in the array of object?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

 class Box{
private:
    double length;
    double height;
    double width;
    //parameterized constructor for the Box class to initialized length, height and width
    public:
    Box(double ilength,double iheight,double iwidth){
    length=ilength;
    height=iheight;
    width=iwidth;
    }

    //calculate the volume
    double getvolume(){
    return length*height*width;
    }
    //calculate the width
    double getarea(){
    return 2*width*length+2*length*height+2*height*width;
    }


};



int main()
{
//Generate the value of length, height and width of every box
double e=(rand()%6)+1;
double f=(rand()%6)+1;
double g=(rand()%6)+1;
double i=(rand()%7)+1;
double j=(rand()%8)+1;
double k=(rand()%9)+1;
double l=(rand()%10)+1;
double m=(rand()%11)+1;
double n=(rand()%12)+1;

cout<<e<<"this is e"<<endl;
cout<<f<<"this is f"<<endl;
cout<<g<<"this is g"<<endl;
cout<<i<<"this is i"<<endl;
cout<<j<<"this is j"<<endl;
cout<<k<<"this is k"<<endl;
cout<<l<<"this is l"<<endl;
cout<<m<<"this is m"<<endl;
cout<<n<<"this is n"<<endl;

Box b[3]={Box(e,f,g),Box(i,j,k),Box(l,m,n)};

double c,d,h,a;
c=b[1].getvolume();
d=b[1].getarea();
h=b[0].getvolume();
a=b[0].getarea();


cout << c <<endl;
cout<< d<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

This works but is there another way better than this?

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In particular, when asking for "better" ways to do something, you should explicitly define what you mean by "better".

Comment: You can use a loop.

Comment: This looks an awful lot like a homework question.

Comment: I think these things would be "better" (but it's a matter of personal opinion):  Use C++ headers instead of C headers.  Do not 'using namespace std', instead selectively use specific identifiers.  Use initializer lists in constructors.  Make the code 'const correct'.  Make the comments reflect the code.  Put a space after a comma.  Put a space around binary operators.  Seed the random number generator.  Make a static Box::MakeRandomBox factory function.

Answer (score 0):

If modulus values can be the same for all boxes I would do something like that:

```
#include <algorithm>    
Box b[3]; 
std::generate(std::begin(b), std::end(b), []()mutable{return Box(rand()%6+1, rand()%7+1, rand()%8+1);});
```

You would need to add default constructor to the Box class:

```
Box() = default;
```